# jQuery optimize efficient for filtering then adding class to multiple element

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-filter

Given a list of elements and I need to filter by some properties and add a class to the qualifying ones.

Since the data set could be large, I'm just wondering if one way is faster than the other

Suppose `listOfElement` is given and consists of lots of elements and I also want to return say the value of each qualifying element

method 1:

```
for(var i = 0; i < listOfElement.length ; i ++){
    if ( testing condition ) {
        $(listOfElement[i]).addClass("blah");
        selected.push(listOfElement[i];
    }
}
```

method 2:

```
selected = listOfElement.filter(...);
$(selected).addClass("blah")
```

I want to know the performance cost for `$` selection operation and the `addClass` operation. It would be great if someone can point me to a document for some JavaScript guide for better performance (e.g. use hide/show is faster than insert/delete a DOM)

Answer (score 0):

Native JavaScript is usually, if not always, faster than jQuery as jQuery involves the creation of `$` objects.

```
var selected = listOfElement.filter(function (item) {
    // ...
});

// Add class
selected.forEach(function (item) {
    item.classList.add('blah'); 
    // If you need to support IE 9 or lower:
    // item.className += ' blah'; // note the space in front of the class name
});
```

[This jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-addclass-vs-dom-classlist/10) may be of interest to you.